# Google DFP / Ad Manager ignoring "Display creatives: Only one" & Per-user frequency when ad units are added programmatically

Tags: php, google-dfp, google-ad-manager

My code:

```
<head>
...
    <script async='async' src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>
    <script>
    var googletag = googletag || {};
    googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
    </script>

    <script>
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
        googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
        googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad();
        googletag.enableServices();
        });
    </script>
...
</head>

<body>
...
    <div id='ad-id-<?php echo $adcount ?>' style='height:600px; width:300px;'>
        <script>
            googletag.cmd.push(function() { 
            var slotname = "ad-id-<?php echo $adcount ?>;
            var slot = googletag.defineSlot('/22#####/ad_300_600', [300, 600], slotname).addService(googletag.pubads());
            googletag.display(slotname);
            googletag.pubads().refresh([slot]);
            });
        </script>
    </div>
...
</body>
```

This runs as part of a loop to place an ad every X rows when the number of rows is unknown.

The issue I'm having is that even with `Display creatives:` set to `Only one` and the `Per-user frequency` set to `1 per 1 minute`, I'm still getting duplicate ads on the page.

There are multiple line items, and each line item has 1 creative. I'd like to show each ad only once.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation ([here](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/3046423?hl=en&ref_topic=4390040)), the push function is declared in the head of the page, and it has to includes :

- sizeMapping (if needed)
- slots definition
- key values set up
- tag options

When unifiying all these elements, you should be able to link creative, apply capping, etc...

With your current implementation, you generate a slot definition for every ad slot. Looks convenient, but you are not pulling ad requests at the same time, so Ad Manager is not able to keep the same correlator between your slots requests.

Here is what you could do (you might need to know how many adslots will be on the page in the head slot definition) :

```
<head>
...
<script async='async' src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>
<script>
var googletag = googletag || {};
googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
</script>

<script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {

    //slots definitions
    googletag.defineSlot('/22#####/ad_300_600', [300, 600], 'ad-id-<?php echo $adcount ?>').addService(googletag.pubads());

    //tag options
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
    googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad();
    googletag.enableServices();
    });
</script>
...
</head>

<body>
...
<div id='ad-id-<?php echo $adcount ?>' style='height:600px; width:300px;'>
</div>
...

<script>
//your loop to generate the ad calls on each "ad-id-" placements
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
  var adunits = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="ad-id-"]');
  for (var i = 0; i < adunits.length; i++) { googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.display(adunits[i].getAttribute('id')); }); }
  });   
</script>
</body>
```

---